# Converting a Utf8 Series into a Series of List<Utf8> via a custom function in Rust polars

Tags: rust, rust-polars

I have a `Utf8` column in my DataFrame, and from that I want to create a column of `List<Utf8>`.

In particular for each row I am taking the text of a HTML document and using `soup` to parse out all the paragraphs of class `<p>`, and store the collection of text of each separate paragraph as a `Vec<String>` or `Vec<&str>`. I have this as a standalone function:

```rust
fn parse_paragraph(s: &str) -> Vec<&str> {

    let soup = Soup::new(s);
    
    soup.tag(p).find_all().iter().map(|&p| p.text()).collect()

}
```

In trying to adapt the few available examples of applying custom functions in Rust polars, I can't seem to get the conversion to compile.

Take this MVP example, using a simpler string-to-vec-of-strings example, borrowing from the [Iterators example from the documentation](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/series/struct.Series.html#iterators):

```rust
use polars::prelude::*;

fn vector_split(text: &str) -> Vec<&str> {

    text.split(' ').collect()
    
}

fn vector_split_series(s: &Series) -> PolarsResult<Series> {

    let output : Series = s.utf8()
        .expect("Text data")
        .into_iter()
        .map(|t| t.map(vector_split))
        .collect();

    Ok(output)
    
}

fn main() {

    let df = df! [
        "text" => ["a cat on the mat", "a bat on the hat", "a gnat on the rat"]
    ].unwrap();

    df.clone().lazy()
        .select([
            col("text").apply(|s| vector_split_series(&s), GetOutput::default())
                .alias("words")
        ])
        .collect();
    
}
```

(Note: I know there is an in-built `split` function for utf8 Series, but I needed a simpler example than parsing HTML)

I get the following error from `cargo check`:

```
error[E0277]: a value of type `polars::prelude::Series` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `Option<Vec<&str>>`
    --> src/main.rs:11:27
     |
11   |       let output : Series = s.utf8()
     |  ___________________________^
12   | |         .expect("Text data")
13   | |         .into_iter()
14   | |         .map(|t| t.map(vector_split))
     | |_____________________________________^ value of type `polars::prelude::Series` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=Option<Vec<&str>>>`
15   |           .collect();
     |            ------- required by a bound introduced by this call
     |
     = help: the trait `FromIterator<Option<Vec<&str>>>` is not implemented for `polars::prelude::Series`
     = help: the following other types implement trait `FromIterator<A>`:
               <polars::prelude::Series as FromIterator<&'a bool>>
               <polars::prelude::Series as FromIterator<&'a f32>>
               <polars::prelude::Series as FromIterator<&'a f64>>
               <polars::prelude::Series as FromIterator<&'a i32>>
               <polars::prelude::Series as FromIterator<&'a i64>>
               <polars::prelude::Series as FromIterator<&'a str>>
               <polars::prelude::Series as FromIterator<&'a u32>>
               <polars::prelude::Series as FromIterator<&'a u64>>
             and 15 others
note: required by a bound in `std::iter::Iterator::collect`
```

What is the correct idiom for this kind of procedure? Is there a simpler way to apply a function?

Comment: Please post the full error of `cargo check`.

Comment: Updated with a MVP and error output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future seekers, I will explain the general solution and then the specific code to make the example work. I'll also point out some gotchas for this specific example.

## Explanation

If you need to use a custom function instead of using the convenient `Expr` expressions, at the core of it you'll need to make a function that converts the `Series` of the input column into a `Series` backed by a `ChunkedArray` of the correct output type. This function is what you give to `map` in the `select` statement in `main`. The type of the ChunkedArray is the type you provide as `GetOutput`.

The code inside `vector_split_series` in the question works for conversion functions of standard numeric types, or List of numeric types. It does not work automatically for `Lists` of `Utf8` strings, for example, as they are treated specially for `ChunkedArrays`. This is for performance reasons. You need to build up the `Series` explicitly, via the correct type builder.

In the question's case, we need to use a `ListUtf8ChunkedBuilder` which will create a `ChunkedArray` of `List<Utf8>`.

So in general, the question's code works for conversion outputs that are numeric or Lists of numerics. But for lists of strings, you need to use a `ListUtf8ChunkedBuilder`.

## Correct code

The correct code for the question's example looks like this:

```rust
use polars::prelude::*;

fn vector_split(text: &str) -> Vec<String> {

    text.split(' ').map(|x| x.to_owned()).collect()
    
}

fn vector_split_series(s: Series) -> PolarsResult<Series> {

    let ca = s.utf8()?;

    let mut builder = ListUtf8ChunkedBuilder::new("words", s.len(), ca.get_values_size());

    ca.into_iter()
        .for_each(|opt_s| match opt_s {
            None => builder.append_null(),
            Some(s) => {
                builder.append_series(
                    &Series::new("words", vector_split(s).into_iter() )
                )
            }});

    Ok(builder.finish().into_series())
    
}

fn main() {

    let df = df! [
        "text" => ["a cat on the mat", "a bat on the hat", "a gnat on the rat"]
    ].unwrap();

    let df2 = df.clone().lazy()
        .select([
            col("text")
                .apply(|s| vector_split_series(s), GetOutput::from_type(DataType::List(Box::new(DataType::Utf8))))

                // Can instead use default if the compiler can determine the types
                //.apply(|s| vector_split_series(s), GetOutput::default())
                .alias("words")
        ])
        .collect()
        .unwrap();

    println!("{:?}", df2);
    
}
```

The core is in `vector_split_series`. It has that function definition to be used in `map`.

The match statement is required because `Series` can have null entries, and to preserve the length of the `Series`, you need to pass nulls through. We use the builder here so it appends the appropriate null.

For non-null entries the builder needs to append `Series`. Normally you can `append_from_iter`, but there is (as of polars 0.26.1) no implementation of FromIterator for `Iterator<Item=Vec<T>>`. So you need to convert the collection into an iterator on values, and that iterator into a new `Series`.

Once the larger `ChunkedArray` (of type `ListUtf8ChunkedArray`) is built, you can convert it into a `PolarsResult<Series>` to return to `map`.

## Gotcha

In the above example, `vector_split` can return `Vec<String>` or `Vec<&str>`. This is because `split` creates its iterator of `&str` in a nice way.

If you are using something more complicated --- like my original example of extracting text via `Soup` queries --- if they output iterators of `&str`, the references may be considered owned by temporary and then you will have issues about returning references to temporaries.

This is why in the working code, I pass `Vec<String>` back to the builder, even though it is not strictly required.